# Joomla's Login doesn't work when I set variable "live_site"

Tags: php, joomla, joomla2.5

I have a Joomla 2.5.7 working with windows server 2013: **SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM/name1/name2**

and this is my admin: **SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM/name1/name2/administrator**

I've set the variable "live_site" to **SUBDOMAIN.DOMAIN.COM/name1/name2**

when I set the live_site, the front-end works fine, but not the back-end, I see: "component not found"
because the component "com_login" is searching in the front-end's component folder

when I don't set the live_site, front-end doesn't works because urls appears so: "http: // [name of the server]/bla/bla/bla", but the backend works fine because the url appears ok

Comment: You should most definitely not be on 2.5.7. You should not normally need live_site. It sounds like your subdomain may not be set up to properly redirect.

Answer (score 0):

I've done a workaround to solve the problem, I modified the file: /libraries/joomla/environment/uri.php
Line 386:

```
$uri .= in_array('host',$parts) ? $this->host : '';
$uri .= in_array('host',$parts) ? 'subdomain.domain.com' : '';
```

perhaps this is not the best solution, but it saved me the trouble.